# Media Mover and thumbnails

Tags: views, media

As it stands now I have MediaMover move images uploaded from Image FUpload CCK to S3 while deleting the source images. However, all I see are lists of the image files that I've uploaded. How can I display a thumbnail instead? I believe that I need to use Views, but I'm a Views noob.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume your media mover process is upload file(s) to site, moved files to S3, copy S3 file location to the CCK field

For Drupal 6:

Install imagecache module and its dependencies.   Create a imagecache preset call thumbnail of the size you want.

Create a view.   Add the CCK field.   In the settings select the format of the thumbnail preset.

[image: views cck field image format settings]